# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

for this code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($mission['Mission']['cadeau'])){ echo

    '<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $this->Html->url("/img/cadeaux/petitscadeaux/".$mission['Missionnature']['name'].".png"); ?>">';  
    }
?>
```

I replace the " with ' but it doesn't work. I also try to add \ but I have always the same message. Someone has an idea how to fix it? Thanks very much !!!!

Comment: Maybe you want to learn a little bit more php, read a book or look at concatenation and single & double quotes

Comment: you don't need open php tag(<?php) in: src="<?php echo $this->Html->u....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have an unclosed string in your code. This is something that slips in easy when you're combining HTML and PHP in the same files. To improve readability, you should move the HTML to a separate template (as you've tagged #cakephp in your question, a template system is built right into the framework). If you insist on keeping the HTML in the PHP file, you can use `printf()` ([docs](http://php.net/printf)) to improve readability of the code.

```
<?php
    if (isset($mission['Mission']['cadeau'])) {
        printf('<img class="img-responsive" src="%s" />', $this->Html->url("/img/cadeaux/petitscadeaux/".$mission['Missionnature']['name'].".png"));  
    }
?>
```